# Value not selected based on ngModel for select

Tags: angular

I got a select were options is fetched from BE, once fetched I populate the options. 
The ngModule was set in another step and is equal to one of the options. 
This result im looking for is that that option that is the same as my modle is shown.

```
    <select class="form-control" id="accident-" [(ngModel)]="accident" required>
      <option *ngFor="let a of accidents" [ngValue]="a">{{a.text | titlecase}}</option>
    </select>
```

Br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses object identity to select option.

To customize the default option comparison algorithm, `<select>` supports `compareWith` input.

**HTML file:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="accident-" [(ngModel)]="accident" required [compareWith]="byAccident">
  <option *ngFor="let a of accidents" [ngValue]="a">{{a.text | titlecase}}</option>
</select>
```

**TS file:**

```
byAccident(item1, item2) {
   return item1 && item2 ? item1.text === item2.text : item1 === item2;
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection

Answer (score 2):

Please add an `id` property to accident objects and then,

```
<select class="form-control" id="accident-" [(ngModel)]="selectedAccident.id" required>
      <option *ngFor="let a of accidents" [ngValue]="a.id">{{a.text | titlecase}} 
      </option>
</select>
```

Here you have to set the `selectedAccident` according to your business requiremet in **TS** file